# Most efficient way to access and change pixels in a QImage

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, qimage

I have a method which manipulates a photo off of a Blackberry.  I currently loop all the pixels and change the RGB values in the original image.  This is primarily for practice to learn both `C++` and `Blackberry 10`.   However, this is some what slow.  I was wondering if there is a better way to do this (for both time and space complexities)?

Code:

```
void PhotoBomberApp::manipulatePhoto2(const QString &fileName)
{
    QImageReader reader;

    // Set image name from the given file name.
    reader.setFileName(fileName);
    QImage image = getRotateImage(fileName); //reader.read();
    QSize imageSize = image.size();
    QColor color;

    for (int i = 0; i < imageSize.width(); i++)
        for (int ii = 0; ii < imageSize.height(); ii++) {
            color = QColor(image.pixel(i, ii));

            if(color.green() > 0 && color.green() > color.red() && color.green() != 255)
                color.setGreen(0);

            if(color.blue() > 0 && color.blue() > color.red() && color.blue() != 255)
                color.setBlue(0);

            image.setPixel(i, ii, color.rgb());
        }


    // Paint an image on top of another image, so we add the gray-scaled image first.
    QPainter merger(&image);

    QString appFolder(QDir::homePath());
    appFolder.chop(4);


    // Save the image.
    image.save(fileName, "JPG");

    // Show the photo by using this function that take use of the InvokeManager.
    showPhotoInCard(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Unless you have *measurements* that show that this operation is a real bottleneck in your application, don't worry. Graphics display and such is probably slower than your program anyway.

Comment: Use profiler, it should tell you how long this takes. There are ways to do it faster but will complicate it